# HTML Dreamweaver Left Margin

Tags: css, dreamweaver, margin

Im trying to create a website using dreamweaver but i am having a small problem with a margin being created on the left which is like a white gap.I have tried to set left margin to 0 using CSS but no luck

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.Header {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(Background/images/images/Untitled-1_01.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.Wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Wrapper">
<div class="Header"></div>
<div>
</div>
  <p>d sdsd </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of the page includes a browser default margin, so you should reset that value once you start editing your CSS, if you don't want to bump in later issues like this.

Copy the following to the top of you CSS file/tags:

```
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

With that you can then remove the unnecessary updates on the margins that you've inserted to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is Because of the default style of browser. You can use reset.css or others like bootstrap.css to Clear browser css. 
Hope this helps 
thanks